# Possible to set Accept-Ranges header on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application with very short-lived(5s) access tokens, paranoid client, and some of their users are accessing the S3 stored files using mobile connections so the lag can be quite high.

I've noticed that Amazon forcefully sends out the `Accept-Ranges` header on all requests, and I'd like to disable that for the files in question. So it would always download the entire file the first time around instead of downloading it chunks.

The main offender I've noticed for this is Chromes built-in PDF viewer. It'll start viewing the PDF, get a 200 response. Then it'll reconnect with a 206 header and start downloading the file in two chunks. If Chrome is too slow to start the download of all chunks before the access token expires it'll keep spamming requests towards S3 (600+ requests when I closed the window).

I've tried setting the header by changing it in the S3 console but while it says it saved it successfully it gets cleared instantly. I also tried to set the header with the signed request, as you can do for `Content-Disposition` for example, but S3 ignored the passed in header.

Or is there any other way to force a client to download the entire file at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's not possible. Made the token expire later in hope it would take care of most cases.

But in case it doesn't make the client happy I will try and proxy it locally and remove all headers I don't like. Following this guide, https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog.

Comment: Is this still the case? I'd like to force download full files from S3 versus allowing 206 partial requests.

Alternatively, possible to do this via Cloudflare or Cloudfront?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know what Amazon supports on this now. In the end everyone was happy with a bit longer on the token expiration and the trade off around that, so we haven't looked back at this since then. :)

Hope you find what you need!

Comment: Thanks it appears the answer is: no. S3 always responds to range requests with a 206, and this doesn't seem to be configurable. I'm working around by essentially using a proxy for a specific use-case.